# Smoothdamp weirdness

Tags: unity-game-engine

```c#
public bool m_controller;
public Vector3 m_velocity;
private float m_curSpd;
private flost m_speedSmoothVelocity;

private Start()
{
    m_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private Update()
{
    if(m_controller.isGrounded)
    {
        m_velocity = GroundVelocity();
    }

    m_controller.Move(m_velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

private Vector3 GroundVelocity()
{
    if(Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        bool run = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        float targetVel = ((run) ? m_runSpeed : m_walkSpeed) * inputX;

        m_curSpd = Mathf.SmoothDamp(m_curSpd, targetVel, ref m_speedSmoothVelocity, 0.06f);
    }

    return new Vector3(m_curSpd, 0, 0);
}
```

I've asked this before, but there was no answer, only downvote...

The problem is: m_velocity.x is acting weirdly far from expectation when this makes the character walk. By looking it works fine, but when I hold down Horizontal key and then stop holding it the m_velocity.x doesn't return to 0 in a normal slow-down fashion, but instead, it(the value) bounces around for about 5 seconds(if m_velocity.x was 20 at getButton, then it bounces around from 0.xxx to 10.xxx "Up and Down not in one way").

At this point, I'm not even sure if this is a bug, or my smoothDamp attempt was wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're not holding the button down, the only code that should run is `return new Vector3(m_curSpd, 0, 0);`

Comment: @Draco18s THANK YOU SOOO MUCH for comment! I think I can take that as new Vector(m_curSpd, 0, 0) which is Vector3.zero always returning, right? However, this issue of mine occurs when it was once moving and input becomes null the weird velocity bouncing happens. Is this still the same case?

Comment: What you probably want to do would be to set up an `else` statement and reset `m_curSpd` to 0.

Comment: @Draco18s OMG... thanks... I'm really embarrassed, actually. You should have posted this as the answer! I'd have gladly picked it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not holding the button down, the only code that should run is `return new Vector3(m_curSpd, 0, 0);`

What you probably want to do would be to set up an `else` statement and reset `m_curSpd` to 0.